# Jquery .click won't console log or alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery:

```
$(".order_submit").click(function() {
  alert( "Alert" );
  console.log("TEST")
});
```

When I put that function in to console I get the following:

```
$(".order_submit").click(function() {
  alert( "Alert" );
  console.log("TEST")
});
[
<input id=​"order_button" type=​"button" class=​"order_submit" value=​"Submit Order">​
]
```

The button is created via this javascript:

```
var total = 0;
    for (var x in prodData) total += prodData[x].price * prodData[x].quantity
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100
    var subtotal = '<tr><td><input id="order_button" type="button" class="order_submit" value="Submit Order"></td><td>Subtotal</td><td>$' + total + '</td></tr>';
```

Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Sounds like you should delegate event  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the button is added to the page after DOMReady you need to use a delegated event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.order_submit', function() {
    alert('Alert');
    console.log('TEST')
});
```

Note that for best performance you should change `document` in my example to the nearest element in the DOM which is present when the page loads. I would imagine this will be the table that `subtotal` gets appended to.

Answer (score 3):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [**Event delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically generated elements

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container for better performance.

*Code*

```
$(document).on('click',".order_submit", function() {
  alert( "Alert" );
  console.log("TEST")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

all you need is delegate coz button is created dynamically

$(document).on('click', ".order_submit", function() {
  alert( "Alert" );
  console.log("TEST")
});

for more information :-

http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

As @A. Wolff said you should delegate event, and you can use for that one of the functions **.on()** or **.delegate()** of jquery, **.on()** for jQuery 1.7+ and **.delegate()** for older versions, take a look at this code:

```
$("table").on("click", ".order_submit", function() {
  alert( "Alert" );
  console.log("TEST")
});
```

you can find the complete code here http://jsfiddle.net/gUY4V/